# Which privilege is required to get both table and synonym for a single user

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle19c

I have 2 users(user1 and user2). user1 has 1 table (i.e. PRODUCT) and user2 has 1 synonym (i.e. PRODUCT). The synonym (PRODUCT) is created with owner USER2. This synonym is created on top of a table, i.e. PRODUCT, and the table owner is USER1.

Statement for table creation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "USER1"."PRODUCT" ( "NAME" VARCHAR2(30)) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "ABC" ;
```

Statement for synonym creation:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM "USER2"."PRODUCT" FOR "USER1"."PRODUCT";
```

Which privilege is required to get both table and synonym for a single user when running below code?

```java
Connection con = null;
Statement statement = null;
String driverClass = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
String host = System.getProperty("host");
String port = System.getProperty("port");
String sid = System.getProperty("sid");
String url = "jdbc:tibcosoftware:oracle://"+host+":"+port+";SID="+sid;
String user = System.getProperty("username");
String password = System.getProperty("password");
try {
    Class.forName(driverClass);
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    if (con != null) {
        System.out.println("Connection created!");
        DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = con.getMetaData();
        // Retrieving the tables
        System.out.println(":::::list of tables:::::");
        ResultSet tablesRS = databaseMetaData.getTables(null, user.toUpperCase(), null, null);
        while (tablesRS.next()) {
            System.out.println(tablesRS.getString(2) + " : " + tablesRS.getString(3) );
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Connection does not created!");
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (statement != null)
            statement.close();
        if (con != null)
            con.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I could not find out which privilege is required to get both table and synonym for a single user. I am getting either table or synonym for corresponding user. I gave select privilege for both the user to get table data and synonym data. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to your [`getTables` call](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)) specifies that you want to filter the results to objects in the `user.toUpperCase()` schema.

```
    ResultSet tablesRS = databaseMetaData.getTables(null, user.toUpperCase(), null, null);
```

Since the objects are in two different schemas, you won't ever get both.  You could pass in a `null` value for the second parameter in order to not filter objects by the schema name.  Or you could pass in a pattern that encompasses both schema names.